# How to write a CAML Query so that the result contains Column1 and Column2?

Tags: sharepoint, caml

My below code is used for filtering based on ID:

```
camlQuery = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");

                camlQuery.InnerXml = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value></Gt></Where>";
```

How to write a CAML Query so that it returns (the result contains) Column1 and Column2?

I'm new to CAML Queries, maybe it's not possible to filter and say only certain columns should be returned?

The problem is that when I run the above query, it returns all the SharePoint columns of my list (42), whereas I only need 2-3.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [SPQuery.ViewFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfields.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN documentation of [`SPQuery.Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.query.aspx) provides a nice example how to use both `Query` property and the `ViewFields` property of the `SPQuery` object:

```
SPList oList = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["List_Name"];
SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
oQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Column1'/><FieldRef Name='Column2'/>";
oQuery.Query = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" + 
               "<Value Type='Number'>0</Value></Gt></Where>";
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.GetItems(oQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the code below:

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
    XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
    XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");

    query.InnerText = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>0</Value></Gt></Where>";
    viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Column1\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Column2\" />";
    queryOptions.InnerXml = "";

    try
    {
        XmlNode ndListItems = listService.GetListItems("List_Name", null, query, viewFields, null, queryOptions, null);
    }
```

For references: [msdn example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems(v=office.12).aspx#Anchor_2)